# Should furring strips be installed before putting vinyl siding over old cedar shake siding?

Tags: vinyl-siding

[image]

I'm thinking about putting vinyl siding over the cedar shake siding. There seems to be very little info for going about this. An old video is the best I could find:

[image]

I would rather not have to repaint the whole house. Any tips or ideas about how to go about putting vinyl siding over the blue house?

Comment: Shingle are laying down flat, appear to be in good shape, is there any specific reason as to why you want to go over them?

Comment: I suppose I was going off my dad's comment how it's not a maintenance free exterior. That must have caused me to think I *need* to either repaint everything or re-side.

Comment: Maintenance free is a sales gimmick. Even vinyl needs to be maintained and when not done properly can cause issues. We have vinyl and there are bees nesting *everywhere* in the J channel.. Personally, I despise vinyl and would choose hardi plank any day of the week, but that's just me. I think what you have there looks like it is in great shape and if it was me, I'd paint it and spend the money on other upgrades.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of using furring strips is to give you a straight nailing surface.

So, if your walls are flat and plumb, you don't need furring, as long as you have a nailing surface.

If the current shakes are nailed to their own furring strips, you can just use longer nails to reach those. If the current shakes are nailed to plywood sheathing, same.

Looking at the condition of the siding on the pictures you posted, I'd rather paint. But that's just my opinion.

Comment: Why would you paint? (I don't know where the cedar is connected.)

Comment: I work alone. Of course it depends on the size of the house and the repairs needed (the worse the siding is, the more I lean to replacing vs. painting), but if the siding is good, painting takes 1/5 of the the time and 1/10th of the cost.

Comment: 190 ft perimeter, two stories 20' of siding: 3800 sq-ft. Vinyl siding alone would cost $2584. Paint would cost, maybe, $600 (so 1/4 the cost). I don't know how long it takes to paint a two story house vs put up siding.

Comment: I am presuming an automatic nailer will make putting up siding take less or as long as two coats of paint. But I do not know.

Comment: Wow... not sure where you live, but only $2600 for the siding sounds like an absolute _steal_ of a deal, @adamaero! Also, you'll be _shocked_ at how much time it takes to hang vinyl siding. There is a _lot_ of fiddly little detail work in getting all the trim pieces cut & fit so that it looks good and not like a hack job. Source: Just got done covering my cement/asbestos siding with vinyl. Oh, on a 2-story house, you're going to want scaffolding, not a ladder, for hanging vinyl. You can get away with a ladder for painting, though scaffold will make it easier & faster.